# How to auto fill the form from the data stored at server in php?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have data stored in form of json on my server. I can access them with url. I want to auto fill my form with that data which is stored on server.

Suppose I have following data:

```
{ "Id": "0", "Name": "Robin" }
```

Which can be accessed by URL:http://192.154.87.59:8888/GetInfo

Now I have a form with two of these fields, Id and Name. I want to do something in which form is auto-filled with these data, which are stored on server. How can I do this in php.

Comment: Is the page written in PHP?

Comment: Have you got any code to show some attempts?

Answer (score 0):

1.Your URL for Ex: yourdomain.com/home.php?id=0

2.Your Code:

```
<?php
$id=$_GET['id'];
include('database-connect.php');
$result=mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM table where id='$id'");
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result);

echo '<form>
<input name="" type="text" value="'.$row['id'].'">
<input name="" type="text" value="'.$row['name'].'">
</form>
';
?>
```

Comment: I need to get data from URL.